# Jackson ignores xml root element for abstract class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, abstract-class

I am migrating an application from Jersey to Spring MVC and I'm having problems to make Jackson work with the legacy xml's. I receive an abstract object on the request body as follow

---

**MyController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = ConnectorConstants.SUBSCRIBE_KEY)
public Callable<SubscribeResult> subscribe(
        @PathVariable final String userKey,
        @RequestBody(required = false) final SubscribeRequest subscribeRequest)
{
    return new Callable<SubscribeResult>()
    {
        @Override
        public SubscribeResult call() throws Exception
        {
            return someService.subscribe(userKey, subscribeRequest);
        }
    };
}
```

---

**SubscribeRequest.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "subscribe_request")
@XmlSeeAlso({ OneRequest.class, AnotherRequest.class, SimpleDomainRequest.class })
public abstract class SubscribeRequest implements Request {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.company.client.request.Request#getBody()
     */
    @Override
    public abstract <K, V> Map<K, V> getBody();

    protected final Map<Object, Object> params = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

}
```

---

**SimpleDomainRequest.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "simple_domain_request")
public class SimpleDomainRequest extends SubscribeRequest
{
    ... methods
}
```

---

**AnotherRequest.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "another_request")
public class AnotherRequest extends SubscribeRequest
{
    ... methods
}
```

---

**OneRequest.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "one_request")
public class OneRequest extends SubscribeRequest
{
    ... methods
}
```

---

Here is one of the xml's the controller receives if the type of the object is SimpleDomainRequest:

```
<simple_domain_request>
  <params>
    <entry>
        <key
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">MY KEY
        </key>
        <value
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">MY VALUE
        </value>
    </entry>
  </params>
</simple_domain_request>
```

So except the controller part that was different when using jersey, I got this code working perfectly fine, the jersey controller was deserializing the object 
without a problem. But after migrating to use Spring-MVC and Jackson it simple can't deserialize it. From what I read Jackson doesn't support @XmlSeeAlso so I tried to do the following changes according to the guides that I found on supporting abstract class with jackson:

**SubscribeRequest**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "subscribe_request")
@XmlSeeAlso({ OneRequest.class, AnotherRequest.class, SimpleDomainRequest.class })
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SimpleDomainRequest.class, name = "simple_domain_request"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AnotherRequest.class, name = "another_request"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = OneRequest.class, name = "one_request")
})   
public abstract class SubscribeRequest implements Request {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.company.client.request.Request#getBody()
     */
    @Override
    public abstract <K, V> Map<K, V> getBody();

    @JsonProperty
    protected final Map<Object, Object> params = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

}
```

But I get the following error from Jackson: *Could not resolve type id 'params'*

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Could not resolve type id 'params' into a subtype of [simple type, class com.company.SubscribeRequest]: known type ids = [SubscribeRequest, one_request, simple_domain_request, another_request]
at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@55416df4; line: 4, column: 13]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.unknownTypeException(DeserializationContext.java:948) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._handleUnknownTypeId(TypeDeserializerBase.java:275) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._findDeserializer(TypeDeserializerBase.java:162) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsWrapperTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.java:100) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.java:49) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserializeWithType(AbstractDeserializer.java:131) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:42) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3562) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2662) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
```

This is my message converters configuration:

```
public class WebConfigurationAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters)
{
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.featuresToEnable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);
    converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(builder.build()));
    converters.add(new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(builder.createXmlMapper(true).build()));
}
```

If I change it to use *UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE*

```
builder.featuresToEnable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
```

Then I get this error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Root name 'params' does not match expected ('SubscribeRequest') for type [simple type, class com.company.SubscribeRequest]
```

If my request body is wrapped in some xml tag then it works:

```
<any_name_here_doesnt_matter>
 <simple_domain_request>
  <params>
    <entry>
        <key
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">MY KEY
        </key>
        <value
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">MY VALUE
        </value>
    </entry>
  </params>
 </simple_domain_request>
</any_name_here_doesnt_matter>
```

Please keep in mind that even thought I have access to the SubscribeRequest class I need to mantain compatibility, so I can't change the xml that I receive.
DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION is there because I use JsonView for other objects.

I might be missing something obvious here so any help is appreciated or if you need to see more of my code.

Pom.xml declaring jackson

```
<properties>
    <woodstox-core-asl.version>4.4.1</woodstox-core-asl.version>
    <jackson.version>2.5.1</jackson.version>
</properties>

    <!-- Jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
        <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${woodstox-core-asl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Spring version is 4.1.5.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "simple_domain_request"`
annotation instead of your `@XmlRootElement(name = "simple_domain_request")`

Comment: I'm very glad you answered it, but after 2 weeks struggling with this issue I gave up. I even opened an issue on their github but the authors couldn't help me. btw I left the company a month ago, so I can't test your suggestion anymore :/